# Too many items in the end is causing my client to disconnect from my realm

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-realms

**Short version:**

Huge number of items in the end, are causing my client to disconnect when I log on to the realm.

Suggestions?

My current plan is to keep logging on to the realm manually, and hope the game clock advances enough each time, that eventually all the items despawn.  I see no other possible solution.

**Longer Explanation on how the situation came about:**

I have a realm.

In the realm, I have been pushing items into End Portals in my overworld, to transport them more efficiently to spawn.

I have been playing one of my kid's accounts on the realm, on the overworld.

I was keeping end chunks loaded (and thus items being processed) by having my personal account (the owner) AFK in the end.

Unfortunately, the end AFK account disconnected, and now when I log on with my owner account, Realms hangs.  When I log in with any user account, I can play fine, as long as I don't go to the end.  If I go to the end, the game hangs, and eventually disconnects.

I am inferring from this, that there are a large number of items in the end, causing the game to lag so massively that all network connections timeout.

My account that can execute commands is in the end, so every time I connect, I disconnect without being able to open a command window.

---

**Updates**

I tried the "log in a bunch of times, to advance the game clock" strategy, but it's pretty clear that the game is 'resetting' to the last saved time.  It is not moving the clock forward.  I'm thinking the game is crashing or hanging.

I tried @Corsaka's idea, at spawn, I set up a command block on a 6 tick timer that executes the command:

> kill @e[type=item]

I tested this on a single player world, and it worked as expected (if I go to the end, items at the end are deleted by the command.)

When I do the same at the realm, the realm just crashes/timesout/resets itself back to a previous saved game state.

Current plan is to download Realm to local machine, and work on it there.  That seems the best solution at this point.  Interested in other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ultimate answer here, is what I proposed above.  Note, this approach is quite general.  If you have a world that is misbehaving on a Realm, for any reason

- Tremendous lag from an out of control farm (too many loose items, or too many entities)
- Tremendous lag from an out of control lag machine
- Commands running amock, causing lag, or getting the game into some other bad state.

Then, the best solution is to

1. Download the world to your local PC.
2. Modify world using any tools at your disposal (in particular, disconnections due to excessive lag are not an issue here)
3. Once the world is fixed up, reload it to your Realm.

---

For what it's worth, I tried Corsaka's suggestion, but the client would disconnect from the server, and reset the server to a time just at the most recent login.

I also tried repeatably logging onto the server to advance the game clock, to attempt to have all the items decay.  In this case, the client would consistently time out, and the game would not advance the game clock.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to **potentially lose all of the dropped items in the overworld** as well, you can get two repeating command blocks and force them to run the following commands repeatedly:

```
/scoreboard players tag @a add inEnd {Dimension:1}
/execute @a[tag=inEnd,c=1] ~ ~ ~ /kill @e[type=item]
```

This adds a tag to any player in the End, and executes a command to kill all items on them. Following this, your plan of action should be:

1. Grant another account temporary admin
2. Use that admin account to set up the two command blocks
3. Log in with owner account (tag is applied, items are deleted. you may need to log in multiple times)
4. Assuming items are deleted, have admin account break the two command blocks
5. Run `/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=inEnd] remove inEnd` on owner account

---

Your method of constantly logging in will also likely work.

Comment: Or you could simply kill all items in end. ```/execute in end run kill @e[type=item]```

Comment: They're not loaded, though @AMJ